# Kivy crashes on launch when importing external libraries

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I used the Kivy Launcher to run a basic "Hello World" program and it worked fine, but when I added in an import cv2 at the beginning, the app crashes immediately after launching.

Main.py:
[Main.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ouG.png)

Android.txt:
[Image of Android.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzubz.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I also tried to replace 'cv2' with 'opencv' in the android.txt file, but that didn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kivy launcher is used to run strictly Kivy modules and Python preinstalled  modules. So in this case, since cv2 doesn't come preinstalled in normal python installations, kivy launcher doesn't recognise it and then gets a "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named cv2" error, which causes it to crash. So, if you're trying to import modules aside from those which come preinstalled with python  you'd have to compile into a .apk file using Buildozer to run it on an android

Comment: So is there no way to import external libraries without using buildozer?

Comment: I know of none, unless you copy and paste all the code in the entire `cv2` module into your python file, because its an issue of a file not found